# Views Sort Criteria: Sort by Taxonomy terms

Tags: views

I have a view that lists team members of a country that are referenced by an Entity reference field.

Now these team members can have different functions and job titles. I assign them through a taxonomy vocabular called "Functions" with the following terms:
- Office Head
- Partner
- Client Partner
- Consultant
- etc.

Usually team members only have one function but the Office Head always has two (Office Head and e.g. Partner).

When I now choose the above taxonomy field as a sort criteria, the office head always appears twice since it has two taxonomy terms assigned. But I only want the office head to show up only once.

Any suggestions how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module. Once you enable this module, for every field there will be a setting **Views Distinct Settings** where you can choose to **filter repeats**.